# How do you work with remote projects and PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, remote-server

My setup is like this:

- The project runs on a LAMP server. I cant run the project on my working machines, they are Windows based and the project needs Linux.
- My IDEs are on different Windows machines (work, home, other_work).
  @work I have PhpStorm @other_work I use a SSH client and edit files with nano or vim and @home I use PhpEd.

How can I keep my project in sync with PhpStorm?

In PhpEd I had never such problems every change is instantly visible in the IDE. I know that I can use the remote Host to see the actual files and change them, but I want to use the project features from the IDE like go to definition.

Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: What's the reason you can't run your project on windows, is the server actually part of the project or could it be run on a windows server? If i understand things right, the best would be to develop the project locally on your Windows machine if that is possible?

Comment: The project runs only under Linux. We have tried to make it run on Windows without success. Locally development is not possible because i develop on different machines.